# Send my PHP page an email address and it replies to it from iOS/Swift application

Tags: php, ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services

New to coding in general, pardon the terrible wording. **This is for a Senior Design project for school** and will have no usage anywhere outside of the project when complete.

Basic concept:
User enters an email address into a text field. They press a button and whatever email address they entered, is sent to the PHP page I'm currently hosting, and it gets a generic reply from that  page. I believe what I'm looking for is a POST request but I could be wrong.

Concept/Screenshots below:

The user enters data into the middle section under "Emergency Contact"

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Op2kp.png)

They then press a contact button to associate the information entered with that contact. It will display a pop up alert and informs them of what they entered and it shifts it to labels below.

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W1y0x.png)

Upon doing this, I'd like to send the email they entered to my PHP script and it replies back. I already have working PHP on it's own. When I go to the address, it sends out an email to what I've specified, but how can I modify it to send to whatever email address the user enters for the email portion? It's going to be for simple proof-of-concept.

We are utilizing AWS for sending of the email and are already out of the Sandboxing phase so we can send to anyone as needed. We just want to be able to show it as a proof of concept during our presentation.

**Thanks for any advice or help.**

**EDIT:**

Here is my current POST setup inside my iOS/Swift button action:
(in my case, c1E is the variable I gave to the contact 1 email address)

```
    /////////////////////////////////
    // Test for Post to php server //

    let url = URL(string: "URL of my PHP")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
    let bodyData = "data=\(c1E)"
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        print(response)

    }
```

So above is what is happening when the button is pressed inside the app.

The PHP is as follows:

```
$postVar = $_POST['data'];
$_POST['data'] = $var
$mail->addAddress ('$var');
```

I don't know how to set up the POST request (sending an email, assuming it is correct) and turning it into a variable which will be read as an email.

Comment: any (named) data from a form will be available after submit in either `$_POST['inputname']` or `$_GET['inputname']` - depending on what you set in `<form method='POST' action='yourScript.php'>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post is indeed the right way to do this. In combination with the [mail()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.

```
<form action="http://somwebsite.com" method="post">
email: <input type="text" name="email"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

The php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['email']){
    $to      = $_POST['email'];
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo "Email was sent".
}
?>
```

You will need to sanitize the email post before using it thought because a spammer could use your form with a crafted email to abuse your IP reputation.

http://www.stevedawson.com/scripts/contact-form.php

Comment: I believe this is getting me on the right track. I'll check it out momentarily. The above code block <form> where would that go? Are you just trying to give me the basic concept of it? Again, I'm going to be doing this from an iOS application and I'm coding with Swift so I'm not too sure how I'd implement that portion, but I do see what it's doing.

Comment: Yes this is only the basic concept. I don't code in Swift... But the concept remains the same. You need to send the post to the handler.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick. I'll check it out and report back on the findings.

Comment: Np I will be around all day. Let me know if you have a related question to the concept or to the PHP side. If it's swift related I would suggest you don't use the PHP tag thought hehe Accept the answer if everything is clear.

Comment: mind taking a look at the edit above, you may be able to chime in

Comment: What does the PHP side receive? Can you show me the result of var_dump($_POST)

Comment: If I'm understanding, the PHP is receiving the email I input to the textfield and submit to it (via the Swift code above). I'm honestly not sure how to utilize var_dump.

Comment: You just type var_dump($_POST); in your PHP and check the request result when you test the submit. But I guess from what I read we can assume it's using $_POST['data']. so replace "email" for "data" in my example and see if that fires an email. If nothing is sent, it could mean 1. Your script is using an other post var then data, 2. your script is not sending anything.